# Error Installing Python Package from Github Using PIP

Tags: python, github, installation, pip, package

Object is to install python package 'opensky-api' from https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api

Used following command at Anaconda prompt.
Logging in with my github username and my token

What mistake is in my command line?

**command line**
(base) C:\Usersr\src\opensky>

```
pip install git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git#egg=opensky
```

**error message**

```
Collecting opensky
  Cloning https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git to c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ovtrt2xb\opensky_9457d92114a54f67b0ed1a53e5ac76c2
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ovtrt2xb\opensky_9457d92114a54f67b0ed1a53e5ac76c2'
  Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
  bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
Username for 'https://github.com':   error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
"my_username@github.com"
  bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
  error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
  stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
Password for 'https://my_password@github.com':
  remote: Invalid username or password.
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git/'
WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git#egg=opensky. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ovtrt2xb\opensky_9457d92114a54f67b0ed1a53e5ac76c2' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opensky (unavailable) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opensky (unavailable)
```

Comment: The repository does not exist. Check the name.

Comment: `remote: Invalid username or password.` <- this looks to be the issue. Can you clone the repository with the same username/password combination?

Comment: @John Haley:  You can see if you load this URL in browser:
https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api

Comment: That is a different repository url.

Comment: @FlyingTeller: I could clone from the public repository without any username/token. Below message:

$ git clone https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api.git
Cloning into 'opensky-api'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 615, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (78/78), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 615 (delta 67), reused 54 (delta 54), pack-reused 537
Receiving objects: 100% (615/615), 6.02 MiB | 1.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (260/260), done.

Comment: @John Hanley:  Your answer is not clear to me. Please explain.
I have used the same URL in the pip command line, as you see in my question above. Viz:

pip install git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git#egg=opensky

Comment: Your question says you used this command line **pip install git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky.git#egg=opensky**. That is a different repository but you start the question with the opensky-api repository. Different names/urls.

Comment: @John Hanley: comment 1/n
thanks. I tried many other URLs and .py files.

Here is another trial using a nested URL:
pip install git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py#egg=opensky

error message returned :
continued in comment 2/n

Comment: @John Hanley: comment 2/n

Collecting opensky
  Cloning https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py to c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dphfh0oj\opensky_b8c8d462277847b2bf97d6fcebe1e1f6
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dphfh0oj\opensky_b8c8d462277847b2bf97d6fcebe1e1f6'
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py/' not found

Comment: @John Hanley: comment 3/n
WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py#egg=opensky.  Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api/tree/master/python/opensky-api.py 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dphfh0oj\opensky_b8c8d462277847b2bf97d6fcebe1e1f6' Check the logs for full command output. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opensky (unavailable) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for opensky (unavailab..

Answer (score 0):

Installation of the package was successful from the local clone using:
pip install C:/Users/opensky/opensky-api/python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).